# How to get data from a REST API (with OAuth2) in Google Big Query

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

The REST API I am thinking about is the one of cloud accounting software Exact Online. I am trying to set this up just using Google Cloud Platform tools.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this guide on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And your question is?